# Order a string and int. High int is on top and the string folow the same order

Tags: c#, arrays

I have some teams:

```
int[] numbers = new int[4];
string[] Teams = {"Team1", "Team2", "Team3","Team4"};
```

they all start with 0 points

```
Team1   0
Team2   0
Team3   3
Team4   0
```

if a team wins gets 3 b.v:(Team1 vs Team3) Team3 won the game. he gets to the  top of the bord. then team wins ...

```
Team3   3
Team1   0
Team2   0
Team4   0
```

I can't find a way to get the **string array** with the highest **int array** on top. in the rith order.
**IT HAS TO BE WITH ARRAY'S.**

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard. You need to find the index of the team with the highest score and then order both arrays

Comment: Can you share your approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a class **Team** similar to as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Team>();
        list.Add(new Team{ Score = 1, TeamName = "Test"});
        list.Add(new Team{ Score = 1, TeamName = "Test 2"});
        list.Add(new Team{ Score = 1, TeamName = "Test 3"});
        list.Add(new Team{ Score = 4, TeamName = "Test 4"});
        list.Add(new Team{ Score = 1, TeamName = "Test 5"});
        
        var ordered = list.OrderByDescending(l => l.Score);
        ordered.Dump();
    }
    
    public class Team
    {
        public int Score {get;set;}
        public string TeamName {get;set;}
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Not sure it makes sense to store a score in a `Team` class, though, does it? A `score` is usually for a particular game (or possibly a series), while a `Team` can be around for many seasons.